# Can't acces the reader on string line = reader.ReadLine();

Tags: c#, exception

```
if (Easy)
{
    try
    {
        reader = File.OpenText(@"../../TxtFiles/eneral_Easy.txt");
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Kan het bestand General_Easy.txt niet vinden!" + ex.Message);
    }
}
else
{
    reader = File.OpenText(@"../../TxtFiles/General_Hard.txt");
}

string line = reader.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    questionList.Add(line);
    line = reader.ReadLine();
}
reader.Close();
NumberOfQuestions = questionList.Count;
```

Comment: What's the question?  Why are you throwing an exception after opening the file?

Comment: If you're getting an error, please paste in the entire text of the error. What do you expect to happen when your code runs?

Comment: @CharlesMager Well I am a beginner so I might be doing something wrong. I wanted to show a message in the console if the file was not found.  And I am getting a NullReferenceException. http://gyazo.com/b46a3a20c8cd59f85dd2ccf51245acf0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.OpenText` will throw an exception if the file is not found.  I'm not sure why you're throwing the exception every time - you can almost certainly remove it.

You catch the exception and write a message, but you don't stop execution here.  By the time you get to `reader.ReadLine()` `reader` has never been instantiated so is `null`.  This is why you get a `NullReferenceException`.  I suspect you want to just return after this fails.

```
try
{
    reader = File.OpenText(@"../../TxtFiles/eneral_Easy.txt");    
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Kan het bestand General_Easy.txt niet vinden!" + ex.Message);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    reader = File.OpenText(@"../../TxtFiles/eneral_Easy.txt");
    throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
```

This code above will always throw an exception, no matter if the file is actually read in or not.

If you want to dump a message to the console when the question file isn't found, you *could* just dump the exception and stack trace to the console - rather simply don't bother with try/catch and let your program crash.

If however, you want to implement some functionality where you design you program to handle such an exception and recover, you can do something like this:

```
try
{
    reader = File.OpenText(@"../../TxtFiles/eneral_Easy.txt");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Kan het bestand General_Easy.txt niet vinden!" + ex.Message);
    var suggestedPath = /* logic to get possible path from another source */ 
    reader = File.OpenText(path); // Will throw again if fails
}
```